# Java Key Listener Error with message about CGSEventRecord

Tags: java

I am learning to make games using java and am trying to implement java.awt.event.KeyAdapter to have keyboard input. My code is working fine except for when I use a key, it gives me what I want, but throws a huge error in the console. I am confused to why I am getting this error, I am following some documentation on how to take key input and it does not mention this problem occurring. How can I have my console not throw this error every time I press down a key?

KeyInput class:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class KeyInput extends KeyAdapter {

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
        int key = event.getKeyCode();

        System.out.println(key);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {

    }
}
```

Then in my main I wrote this code to have my game be listening for keys being pressed

```
this.addKeyListener(new KeyInput());
```

This should return the ID for each key, and it does. However the console is returning this error along with the correct ID.

```
2018-08-12 12:32:03.635 java[58065:6573813] -_cgsEventRecord is deprecated for _cgsEventRecord. Please use -CGEvent.
2018-08-12 12:32:03.635 java[58065:6573813] *** Assertion failure in -[NSEvent _cgsEventRecord], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppKit/AppKit-1561.40.112/AppKit.subproj/NSEvent.m:1972
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Non-Java exception raised, not handled! (Original problem: Deprecated in 10_12... DO NOT EVER USE CGSEventRecord directly. Bad things, man.... bad things.)
at apple.awt.ComponentModel._handleEvent(Native Method)
at apple.awt.ComponentModel.handleEvent(ComponentModel.java:273)
at apple.awt.CWindow.handleEvent(CWindow.java:545)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:753)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1000)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:865)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:686)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4648)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2142)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2492)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:690)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:687)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: I would add that this error is not restricted to Java Key Listeners. I encountered it with old code that had no Key Listeners when entering characters in a JTextField with no listeners on that field, and without clicking the button that had an action event to read the field. This had worked ok on Mac El Capitan, but not on High Sierra. Setting the Java version to 1.8, as in the answer from @ThomasWelller fixed things, as I mention in a comment to his answer.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you're using Java 6 and should upgrade to Java 8.

I got that pointer from the message

> Non-Java exception raised, not handled! (Original problem: Deprecated in 10_12... DO NOT EVER USE CGSEventRecord directly. Bad things, man.... bad things.

Comment: Additional note. If the poster is using a version of Eclipse that supports Java 1.8 (Neon and higher?) and has both java 1.6 and 1.8 installed he can change from 1.6 to 1.8 in his project properties.